# Three-parameter beta function fit

Tags: r, beta-distribution

I'm looking for the way to fit a three-parameter beta function on my profile data.

---

The data looks like this ("Data" dataframe at the end of the post):

```
ggplot2::ggplot(Data, aes(x=CL, y=CW, color=id)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

---

```
str(Data)
'data.frame':   125 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id: Factor w/ 4 levels "1803","1804",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CL: num  0 0.0333 0.0667 0.1 0.1333 ...
 $ CW: num  0.152 0.224 0.224 0.261 0.284 ...
```

---

My first attempt to fit such a model was as follows:

```
M2 <- nls(Data$CW ~ (Data$CL^r) * (1-Data$CL)^s, start=list(r=1, s=1))
summary(M2)

Formula: Data$CW ~ (Data$CL^r) * (1 - Data$CL)^s

Parameters:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
r  0.62079    0.01240   50.07   <2e-16 ***
s  0.75161    0.01444   52.06   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0385 on 123 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.713e-06
```

---

Given that in my data (those exposed here are only a small representative sample), **CL** can take any value between 1 and 0, different authors, in previous works and with data of the same nature, follow another approach and fit a model of the shape...

[image]

They said that β0 parameter is a scaling term added to fit
the x-values of the points when *CL* was constrained between 0 and 1, and 
β1 and β2 are the distribution shape parameters.

Although I understand that the approximation of these authors is the right one to fit beta models to data like mine, my knowledge in statistics is not so deep as to find a way to fit such a model in R.

So I wanted to ask somebody to help me face this challenge!

Any comment will be welcome!

Regards!

---

## EDIT

I tried to fit a model like the one I mentioned,
and this is the result:

```
 CL <- Data$CL
 CW <- Data$CW
 M2 <- nls(CW ~ b0*(((CL^(b1-1)) * (1-CL)^(b2-1)) /
                    beta(b1, b2)),
           start=list(b0=1, b1=1, b2=1))

 summary(M2)

 Formula: CW ~ b0 * (((CL^(b1 - 1)) * (1 - CL)^(b2 - 1))/beta(b1, b2))

Parameters:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
b0 0.285326   0.003471   82.19   <2e-16 ***
b1 1.570795   0.034280   45.82   <2e-16 ***
b2 1.694634   0.038424   44.10   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0383 on 122 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.054e-06
```

In addition, I have plotted the results, and they seem quite adequate.

```
plot(CW ~ CL)
points(predict(M2) ~ CL, col = 2, pch=19, cex=0.7)
```

[image]

But again, I'm not sure if it's the right way to model this data.
Any help will be welcome.

Greetings!

---

Data

```
      id         CL          CW
1   1803 0.00000000 0.151621395
2   1803 0.03333333 0.224103160
3   1803 0.06666667 0.223510555
4   1803 0.10000000 0.260757605
5   1803 0.13333333 0.284124839
6   1803 0.16666667 0.327629619
7   1803 0.20000000 0.324783558
8   1803 0.23333333 0.323214381
9   1803 0.26666667 0.348361370
10  1803 0.30000000 0.362845016
11  1803 0.33333333 0.378936837
12  1803 0.36666667 0.382478651
13  1803 0.40000000 0.391898609
14  1803 0.43333333 0.385987967
15  1803 0.46666667 0.374831225
16  1803 0.50000000 0.375420490
17  1803 0.53333333 0.366602656
18  1803 0.56666667 0.348868631
19  1803 0.60000000 0.334440663
20  1803 0.63333333 0.310161766
21  1803 0.66666667 0.305783468
22  1803 0.70000000 0.280365579
23  1803 0.73333333 0.267783763
24  1803 0.76666667 0.245834637
25  1803 0.80000000 0.241571547
26  1803 0.83333333 0.231955195
27  1803 0.86666667 0.213391653
28  1803 0.90000000 0.166491699
29  1803 0.93333333 0.146278836
30  1803 0.96666667 0.134303984
31  1803 1.00000000 0.098171870
32  1804 0.00000000 0.120097530
33  1804 0.05000000 0.227869042
34  1804 0.10000000 0.271310083
35  1804 0.15000000 0.281034945
36  1804 0.20000000 0.318685971
37  1804 0.25000000 0.338954237
38  1804 0.30000000 0.327764529
39  1804 0.35000000 0.345350164
40  1804 0.40000000 0.352477414
41  1804 0.45000000 0.354587655
42  1804 0.50000000 0.349216946
43  1804 0.55000000 0.337041304
44  1804 0.60000000 0.329580413
45  1804 0.65000000 0.330334085
46  1804 0.70000000 0.306919911
47  1804 0.75000000 0.230689042
48  1804 0.80000000 0.230041341
49  1804 0.85000000 0.170136137
50  1804 0.90000000 0.154509681
51  1804 0.95000000 0.076608345
52  1804 1.00000000 0.048860251
53  1805 0.00000000 0.028495877
54  1805 0.02857143 0.107077785
55  1805 0.05714286 0.139833192
56  1805 0.08571429 0.163497811
57  1805 0.11428571 0.192341894
58  1805 0.14285714 0.274626937
59  1805 0.17142857 0.301248731
60  1805 0.20000000 0.328679902
61  1805 0.22857143 0.338225776
62  1805 0.25714286 0.346386112
63  1805 0.28571429 0.353991747
64  1805 0.31428571 0.312520665
65  1805 0.34285714 0.327987422
66  1805 0.37142857 0.344788338
67  1805 0.40000000 0.358323617
68  1805 0.42857143 0.359364534
69  1805 0.45714286 0.364390855
70  1805 0.48571429 0.366922457
71  1805 0.51428571 0.369744301
72  1805 0.54285714 0.372980445
73  1805 0.57142857 0.380225135
74  1805 0.60000000 0.374934714
75  1805 0.62857143 0.363140797
76  1805 0.65714286 0.359816167
77  1805 0.68571429 0.356915838
78  1805 0.71428571 0.328185423
79  1805 0.74285714 0.303022537
80  1805 0.77142857 0.290881358
81  1805 0.80000000 0.286946550
82  1805 0.82857143 0.224159517
83  1805 0.85714286 0.211407915
84  1805 0.88571429 0.167520861
85  1805 0.91428571 0.165864610
86  1805 0.94285714 0.145412761
87  1805 0.97142857 0.126027829
88  1805 1.00000000 0.065972725
89  1806 0.00000000 0.005540865
90  1806 0.02777778 0.070305695
91  1806 0.05555556 0.086195631
92  1806 0.08333333 0.095006044
93  1806 0.11111111 0.208133063
94  1806 0.13888889 0.230062694
95  1806 0.16666667 0.266365235
96  1806 0.19444444 0.344292427
97  1806 0.22222222 0.343846279
98  1806 0.25000000 0.353878699
99  1806 0.27777778 0.387860550
100 1806 0.30555556 0.408561309
101 1806 0.33333333 0.417591584
102 1806 0.36111111 0.401206073
103 1806 0.38888889 0.422161556
104 1806 0.41666667 0.429408101
105 1806 0.44444444 0.428978907
106 1806 0.47222222 0.419754810
107 1806 0.50000000 0.407545594
108 1806 0.52777778 0.425385454
109 1806 0.55555556 0.410136310
110 1806 0.58333333 0.394142101
111 1806 0.61111111 0.369455638
112 1806 0.63888889 0.367706430
113 1806 0.66666667 0.361984333
114 1806 0.69444444 0.351615802
115 1806 0.72222222 0.336034163
116 1806 0.75000000 0.311916744
117 1806 0.77777778 0.295645520
118 1806 0.80555556 0.281931495
119 1806 0.83333333 0.233309239
120 1806 0.86111111 0.217580393
121 1806 0.88888889 0.196212349
122 1806 0.91666667 0.186176362
123 1806 0.94444444 0.179800856
124 1806 0.97222222 0.086905072
125 1806 1.00000000 0.017521754
```

Comment: In particular, consider including ID in the model and test for significant differences between subjects.

Comment: the main difference between your first and second models is that the first constrains b0/beta(b1,b2)=1. When I fitted these data (with a slightly different parameterization) that value came out to 0.91, so there isn't much difference between the two models (unless you have a theoretical reason to constrain the area under the curve to 1, the second model probably makes more sense).

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the code dump.

Get data:

```
dd <- read.table("betafit.txt",header=TRUE)
dd$id <- factor(dd$id)
```

Your first model:

```
M1 <- nls(CW ~ (CL^r) * (1-CL)^s, 
          data=dd,
          start=list(r=1, s=1))
summary(M1)
```

Two versions of the model with the third parameter:

```
M2 <- nls(CW ~ b0*(CL^r)*(1-CL)^s,
          data=dd,start=list(b0=1,r=1,s=1))
M3 <- nls(CW ~ b0*dbeta(CL,shape1=r,shape2=s),
          data=dd,start=list(b0=1,r=1,s=1))
```

One way to test that these are actually the same is to compare residual SE:

```
sigma(M2)==sigma(M3)
```

Make predictions for all three models and plot them:

```
pframe <- data.frame(CL=seq(0,1,length.out=51))
allpred <- data.frame(model=rep(c("M1","M2","M3"),each=nrow(pframe)),
           CL=rep(pframe$CL,3),
           CW=unlist(lapply(list(M1,M2,M3),predict,newdata=pframe)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd,aes(x=CL, y=CW)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=id))+
  geom_line(data=allpred,aes(linetype=model))
```

As suggested in comments, you can fit the model allowing parameters to vary across `id`. This version allows all three parameters to vary ...

```
library(nlme)
M4 <- gnls(CW ~ b0*dbeta(CL,shape1=r,shape2=s),
          params=b0+r+s~id,
          data=dd,start=list(b0=c(1,0,0,0),
                             r=c(1,0,0,0),
                             s=c(1,0,0,0)))
```

You can test differences between models with `anova()` (see `?anova.gls`) ...

Comment: Hi [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/87647796?noredirect=1)

I wonder if you could recommend a way to fit this three-parameter beta function with a mixed model. The idea is to control the variability associated with "id" (or to different groups of "id"). I would like to test these groups as "random effects" modifying the three beta parameters (b0, r, s).